# How to fix the issue of controls shifting on high DPI?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I came across this Microsoft article on how to support high DPI in Windows Forms applications running on .NET Framework 4.7.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms

I followed those instructions and they did help me fix the blurring issue, but I still can't figure out a way to fix the controls shifting/moving.

I tried to place all controls in a TableLayoutPanel and adjust the anchors, but it didn't solve the issue.

So, is there a way to fix this issue?

PS: I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2 and Windows 10 Pro 1909

Comment: Your Forms are probably set to auto-scale to Font and some of your controls inherit the Font from the Parent. Of course your current layout is unknow and you didn't mention what you changed in the configuration files (and/or what Win32 functions you used) to comply with the High-Dpi/DpiAwareness requirements, but test the app setting `AutoScaleMode = Dpi` and also set the Font explicitly in each Control (so it won't inherit it, even if the Font is the same as the Parent's). Note that UserControls have their own `AutoscaleMode`.

Comment: @Jimi What I did is enable Windows 10 compatibility in the manifest and set DpiAwareness to PerMonitorV2 which helped fix the blurriness. 

Anyway, setting AutoScaleMode = Dpi helped fix the issue of controls shifting. I can't believe it was that simple. If you can add it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `AutoScaleMode = Dpi` solved the issue for me.
Thanks to [@Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi)